# HTTP post c# object to NodeJS api

Tags: c#, node.js, .net

I want to post an object from C# to a NodeJS API however the object gets wrapped in extra brackets and quotes.

When I try to do the same request in postman, it works just fine.

C# code:

```cs
public void SendCertificate(CertificateDTO dto)
        {
          
            var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            _client.PostAsync("http://localhost:3000/mailcertificate", stringContent);
        }
```

(_client being the HttpClient instance)

NodeJS console output.
I just console.log(req.body) here:

```sh
{
'{"Id":"786","FirstName":"Simon","LastName":"Says","Email":"simonsays@test.com","Distance":"4562km","Date":"may12"}': ''
}
```

The prefered output should be:

```sh
{
  id: '786',
  firstname: 'Simon',
  lastname: 'Says',
  email: 'simonsays@test.com',
  sistance: '4562km',
  date: 'may12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When creating the content yourself from scratch it works :)

I hope this post can help someone else out, took me a lot of time xD

```cs
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"id", dto.Id},
                    {"firstname", dto.FirstName},
                    {"lastname", dto.LastName},
                    {"email", dto.Email},
                    {"distance", dto.Distance},
                    {"date", dto.Date}
                }
            );

            _client.PostAsync("http://localhost:3000/mailcertificate", content);
```